# glib errors on cygwin

Tags: makefile

I want to compile and install geany text editor in Windows 7 by using cygwin.
I follow the usual way to compile and install C source:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

the configure script was successfully running and give me no errors.In the `make` step i have the following errors :

```
ctags.c:23:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
#include <glib.h>
```

I have installed pkg-config and also add the pkg-config output to makefile by doing the
following:

```
CFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)
CXXFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)
LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs glib-2.0)
```

This is the output of the pkg-config

```
$pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lpcre -lintl - liconv -lpcre


$ pkg-config --libs glib-2.0
-lglib-2.0 -lintl -lpcre -lintl -liconv -lpcre
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Although this is possible, [I would like to point out that there is already a Windows version of geany](http://www.geany.org/Download/Releases).**

If you'd rather build this manually under cygwin, the [geany documentation for building from their git repo](http://www.geany.org/Download/Git) seems to encourage the use of `Autotools` to generate a configure script.

The following worked for me on Win7 64 bit using Cygwin 64 bit after cloning the geany repo.

```
./autogen.sh --disable-html-docs
make
make install
```

You *must* have `xinit` installed in Cygwin, and you also need a lot of other libraries installed for this to build and run.

[Here is a ridiculous list I generated using `cygcheck -c` of all my installed packages](https://gist.github.com/williamhaley/b36dba6549ed8fbf3bdf).  You need many, but not all of these to build geany.  Sorry, but I don't know exactly which are mandatory and which are not.

Eventually, once it installs and builds, you can run `startxwin` from within Cygwin to start an `xterm` session.  Then you can run `geany`.

[image]

Comment: I've tried using the command above.But an error occured
`**Error**: You must have `automake' (1.7 or later) installed.`

In the /usr/bin directory there is a lot of gnu autotools installed but 
why ./autogen.sh keep give that error...?

Comment: If you type `automake --version` does it say you have version 1.7 or later installed?  Did you use cygwin's setup exe file to install automake?  You need to install version 1.7 or newer of automake.  I installed version 1.14 on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [wiki](http://wiki.geany.org/howtos/win32/build) on how to build on widows. Building with autotools is currently not supported, when directly building on windows.